# Could not build c++ projects targeting windows 8.1 in VS2015. Unresolved external symbol _sprintf

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

I can't build a VC++ project targeting windows 8.1 in a windows 10 machine. The error I'm getting is **"Unresolved external symbol _sprintf"**. I can only build the project if I changed the target platform to Windows 10 or if I added `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`. Which I don't want to do. I can build this project before without doing that. And my co workers can build the same code in their machine. The question is, what am I missing on my machine?

I already tried to update visual studio to the latest. I also tried to repair visual studio from *Programs and Features*.

Answer (score 0):

_sprintf is defined in stdio.h. if you `#include <stdio.h>` you can then use it.
  It's an old function. see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx)
for more information regarding that function and it's use. C++ has templated versions of the functions detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175759.aspx). The function though is part of the CRT library, and has been for quite some time. Check your linkage and make sure your liking to the CRT that has it, and in your case it would be legacy_stdio_definitions.lib. Before you changed your build target it was probably automatically being linked into the project, and that setting did not revert back to that when you reverted your build target back. Your problem though is with the project settings, not visual studio or the compiler it's self.

Comment: The same code builds on other machine. My co-worker can build it on his machine without changing the target platform or adding legacy_stdio_definitions.lib.

Comment: probably because his machine already links to legacy_stdio_definitions.lib. A lot of those old string functions are deprecated, which is why they got moved to 'legacy_stdio_definitions.lib'

Comment: Now how can I do that to my machine without updating the projects?

Comment: you have to update your projects. That's all that's needed. Add the library to your link list.

Comment: Is there another way aside from updating the project? Like what I said, my co-workers have the same source, the same project. Without updating the project they can build it.